# More efficient word boundary query in mySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with 1/2 million phrases and I am doing word matching using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `searchIndex` WHERE `indexData` RLIKE '[[:<:]]Hirt'
```

The indexData field has a FULLTEXT index and is datatype longtext.

I want to match on items like

"Alois M. Hirt"

"Show Biz - Al Hirt, in a new role, ..."

"Al Hirt's Sinatraville open 9 p..."

"Hirt will be playing..."

and not on "shirt" or "thirteen" or "thirty" etc.

The query is succeeding but it frequently takes 3 seconds to return and I wondered if there was a better, more efficient way of doing this word boundary match?

If I were to add another index to indexData what would be the correct keylength to use?

TIA

Comment: try to use FULLTEXT search first follow by the regex

Comment: SELECT * FROM `searchIndex` WHERE MATCH (`indexData`)
AGAINST ('Hirt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Comment: Thanks setsuna!  That client now has an in-house developer. I have passed this along to him.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh if this question has been answered, then you should either give an answer your own, or delete it altogether.

Comment: I had similar problem, but in my case phrases could be also multiword. Adding a like check (... LIKE '%phrase%' AND ...) before regexp check increased speed by much (so regexp was checked only when there was phrase in article at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setsuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920374/setsuna)'s answer worked very well:

SELECT * FROM searchIndex WHERE MATCH (indexData) AGAINST ('Hirt*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Answer (score 6):

No need to have a FULLTEXT index. MySQL has **special markers for word boundaries**. From the [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
[[:<:]], [[:>:]]
```

These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (_).

```
mysql> SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';   -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'a xword a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';  -> 0
```